# Chrome Dev Tools Network panel does not show pending XHR requests issued by a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chrome Extension that is issuing XHR requests.

The network panel in Chrome Dev Tools is not showing pending requests issued by that extension. The requests only start showing up when they have completed (successfully or not)

Is this a known issue? Is there another way to see pending requests ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools or maybe you opened it after the extension started the request.